# Mysql fulltext search didn't find exact phrase

Tags: mysql, search, indexing, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I have a table with column name with fulltext index -

[image]

In this table there is many rows but some of them contain the phrase "aberlour 18" exactly at start like here -

[image]

But when I search using the fulltext search with exact name from the table  -

```
SELECT * FROM `whiskybase_bottles` WHERE MATCH(`name`) AGAINST('Aberlour 18 year old')
```

It finds it only on 6th place -

[image]

How can I improve it to find it first?

I don't want to use "LIKE" search because fulltext works better for my needs on other cases.

I already decreased the "innodb ft min token size" param to be 2 instead of 3 to include the age statement and recreated the index after it -

[image]

Comment: Did you rebuild the FT index in question _after_ changing ft_min_token_size?

Comment: Yes, like I wrote I recreated it after the change

Comment: Can you provide a simple test case for us to work with?  Just a few dozen rows with the `id` and `name` column.  Please verify that the test fails.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find rows that have "Aberlour 18 year old" included in the name but not necessarily the entire name, you can use the + operator that is used for boolean full text searches. Without the + operator, your query is searching for phrases that match the search exactly and does not select phrases that have other words and characters like you want.
Your code would look something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `whiskybase_bottles` 
WHERE MATCH(`name`) AGAINST('+"Aberlour 18 year old"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

You can learn more about BOOLEAN MODE and the related operators here:
https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-full-text-search-functions.php

For a general search with a variable you can do something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `whiskybase_bottles` 
WHERE MATCH(`name`) AGAINST(concat('+\"', search_phrase, '\"') IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Comment: Yes I know this feature, but what is the reason that without it it not finds it on the first place?
In this solution it will work bad when the search phrase is not exact... I need a general solution

Comment: It is not finding it because it is searching for entries that match the string exactly, not entries that contain the string but have more characters. The plus sign is necessary to find strings that are not exact but contained in the phrase. You could also put a plus sign in front of every word if you are searching for the words in the phrase that are not in an exact order.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rank the exact phrase on the top.

Use this code instead:

```
SELECT *,MATCH (name) AGAINST( 'Aberlour 18 year old' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as score
 FROM `whiskybase_bottles` 
WHERE MATCH(`name`) AGAINST('Aberlour 18 year old')
 ORDER BY name = 'Aberlour 18 year old' DESC, score DESC
```